# Crear Agenda Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy creando una agenda donde se puedan agregar contactos, y después los muestro, pero cuando le doy la opción de que me muestre el contacto, solo me muestra uno y no me muestra todos los que guarde

```
def e2():
    contactos = []
    class clsContacto () :
        nombre = ""
        apellido= ""
        telefono = ""
    while True:
        print("Bienvenido a la AGENDA");
        print("1 si desea agregar un contacto")
        print("2 si desea ver un contacto");
        print("3 si desea eliminar un contacto");
        opcion = input("Escriba una opcion :  ");
        if opcion == "1" :
            print("Agregar Contacto");
            contacto =  clsContacto ()
            contacto.nombre = input("Escriba un nombre");
            contacto.apellido = input("Escriba un apellido");
            contacto.telefono = input("Escriba un telefono");
            contactos.append (contacto)
        elif opcion == "2" :
            print("Contactos agregados");
            for contacto in contactos :
                print("nombre \t apellido  \t telefono");
                print(contacto.nombre + "\t" +contacto.apellido + "\t" +contacto.telefono);
                input()
                e2();

e2()
```

Comment: Buenos días Daniela al final de la opción 1 llamas a la función e2, esta función  limpia la lista de contactos por lo que al preguntar por la opción 2 no hay contactos. Aún así me parece que tendrías que usar algún bucle no se como haces para preguntar varias veces sin uno.

Comment: @lDanny7  muchas gracias por tu ayuda y tenias razón, necesitaba un bucle 

Ahora solo tengo que arreglar que me muestre todos los contactos que guardo mi código quedo así

Comment: Y quita los `;` al final de cada línea. En python no hacen falta :-)

Comment: No debes llamar a la función `e2()` desde dentro de sí misma ¿qué propósito tiene esa llamada? Por otro lado, si estás empezando acostúmbrate desde el principio a buenas prácticas a la hora de elegir nombres. El nombre de función `e2()`  no da ninguna pista de para qué sirve. Llámala por ejemplo `crear_y_mostrar_agenda()`. A python no le importa que pongas nombres largos (no es más lento por ello) y a tí, si usas un buen editor que te ayude a autocompletar, tampoco te importará teclearlos. Pero lo agradecerás cuando leas el código un tiempo después y ya no recuerdes bien qué hacía.